# Как и чем парсить Json на Java?

Tags: java, json, java-faq

Часто возникает потребность работы с *Json*, в частности его чтения и парсинга. В *Java* обычно ты знаешь с каким типом переменных работаешь, а при парсинге *Json* смущает то, что тип полей может быть любой.

Какие есть способы разбора *Json*? Как это делать?

Вот, допустим, как достать данные из *Json*, представленного ниже?

```
{
    "firstName": "Json",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "666 1nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": 10021
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "542 666-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "653 666-4567" 
        }
    ],
    "friends": [
        {
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Snow",
            "age": 20,
            "phoneNumbers": [
                {
                    "type": "home",
                    "number": "141 111-1234"
                }
            ],
            "friends": [
                {
                    "firstName": "UnknownFirstName",
                    "lastName": "UnknownLastName",
                    "age": 999,
                    "phoneNumbers": [
                        {
                            "type": "home",
                            "number": "000 000-0000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Flash",
            "lastName": "Tompson",
            "age": 23,
            "phoneNumbers": [
                {
                    "type": "home",
                    "number": "999 111-1234"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Достать данные можно разными способами и, конечно, зависит от задач. Попробую рассмотреть некоторые варианты разбора *Json*.

**Заметка:** для каждого из примеров для парсинга будет взят *Json* из вопроса, чтобы зря не копировать в ответ.

---

## Simple Json

**Где взять:**  [здесь](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/json-simple.htm) / [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) / или через *Maven* и пр.

Это самый примитивный способ. По сути, всё, что тут есть - это `JSONObject` и `JSONArray`.

- `JSONArray` может включать в себя несколько объектов `JSONObject`, его можно обходить циклом на каждой итерации получая объект `JSONObject`.
- `JSONObject` - объект, из которого можно доставать его отдельные свойства.

Я бы использовал его для небольших *Json* строк, где не надо сильно заморачиваться или если не лень писать свой класс-обработчик на основе кода, который продемонстрирован ниже:

```
// Считываем json
Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(jsonString); // Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("JSONExample.json"));
// Кастим obj в JSONObject
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
// Достаём firstName and lastName
String firstName = (String) jo.get("firstName"); 
String lastName = (String) jo.get("lastName");
System.out.println("fio: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
// Достаем массив номеров
JSONArray phoneNumbersArr = (JSONArray) jo.get("phoneNumbers");
Iterator phonesItr = phoneNumbersArr.iterator();
System.out.println("phoneNumbers:");
// Выводим в цикле данные массива
while (phonesItr.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject test = (JSONObject) phonesItr.next();
    System.out.println("- type: " + test.get("type") + ", phone: " + test.get("number"));
}
```

Остальная работа с вложенными массивами аналогична. Можно складывать в List, Map и пр.

---

### GSON

**Где взять:** [здесь](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/gson.htm) / [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/google/gson) / или через *Maven* и пр.

**Документация:** http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction/

Позволяет парсить *Json* также, как и *Json-simple*, т.е. используя `JSONObject` и `JSONArray` (см. [документацию](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction/)), но имеет более мощный инструмент парсинга. 
Достаточно создать классы, которые повторяют структуру *Json*'а. Для парсинга *Json* из вопроса создадим классы:

```
class Person {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;
    public Address address;
    public List<Phones> phoneNumbers;
    public List<Person> friends;
}

class Address {
    public String streetAddress;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public int postalCode;
}

class Phones {
    public String type;
    public String number;
}
```

Теперь достаточно написать:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Person person = g.fromJson(jsonString, Person.class);
```

Всё! Магия! Чудо! Теперь в `person` лежит объект с типом `Person`, в котором находятся данные именно с теми типами, которые были указаны в созданных классах! 
Теперь можно работать с любым типом, как это привыкли всегда делать: String, Integer, List, Map и всё остальное.

```
// Выведет фамилии всех друзей с их телефонами
for (Person friend : person.friends) {
    System.out.print(friend.lastName);
    for (Phones phone : friend.phoneNumbers) {
        System.out.println(" - phone type: " + phone.type + ", phone number : " + phone.number);
    }
}

// output:
// Snow - phone type: home, phone number : 141 111-1234
// Tompson - phone type: home, phone number : 999 111-1234
```

**Пример парсинга в `Map`:**

...... *JSON* для разбора:

```js
{  
 "2":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"13:00",
    "price":"410"
   },
   {  
    "time":"06:40",
    "price":"340"
   },
   {  
    "time":"16:50",
    "price":"370"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-L",
  "locate":"Москва, Садовая-Спасская ул., 21, 56",
  "metro":"Красные ворота"
 },
 "7":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"06:35",
    "price":"190"
   },
   {  
    "time":"00:05",
    "price":"410"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-V",
  "locate":"Павелецкая пл., 2, строение 1",
  "metro":"Павелецкая"
 },
 "8":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"15:10",
    "price":"330"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-J",
  "locate":"ул. Пречистенка, 40/2",
  "metro":"Кропоткинская"
 },
 "9":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"13:00",
    "price":"600"
   },
   {  
    "time":"08:30",
    "price":"300"
   },
   {  
    "time":"04:00",
    "price":"510"
   },
   {  
    "time":"13:15",
    "price":"340"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-U",
  "locate":"Шарикоподшипниковская ул., 24",
  "metro":"Дубровка"
 }
}
```

...... Классы (POJO):

```
class Seanse {
    public String name;
    public String locate
    public String metro;
    public List<Sessions> sessions;
}

class Sessions {
    public String time;
    public double price;
}
```

...... Сам разбор выглядит так:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Seanse>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Seanse> myMap = g.fromJson(json, type);
```

Всё.

Дополнительно в *GSON*  можно использовать аннотации, например: исключить указанные поля при парсинге, поменять имя переменной (например не `personFirstName`, а `fName`) и многое другое. Подробнее см. в [документации](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

---

### Jackson

**Где взять:** [здесь](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/jackson-all.htm) / [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) / или через *Maven* и пр.

**Документация и примеры:** https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Как и *GSON* он также позволяет работать используя `JSONObject` и `JSONArray` если это требуется, и тоже умеет парсить на основе предоставленных классов (см. пример ниже).

Аналогично в нем можно указывать дополнительные требования за счет аннотаций, например: не парсить указанные поля, использовать кастомный конструктор класса, поменять имя переменной (например не `firstName`, а `fName`) и многое другое.
Подробнее см. в [документации](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs).

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);

System.out.println("My fio: " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " and my friends are: ");
for (Person friend : person.friends) {
    System.out.print(friend.lastName);
    for (Phones phone : friend.phoneNumbers) {
        System.out.println(" - phone type: " + phone.type + ", phone number : " + phone.number);
    }
}

// output:
// My fio: Json Smith and my friends are: 
// Snow - phone type: home, phone number : 141 111-1234
// Tompson - phone type: home, phone number : 999 111-1234
```

---

### JsonPath

**Где взять:** через *Maven* и другие сборщики / [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Относится к так называемым **XPath** библиотекам. Её суть аналогична `xpath` в *xml*,  то есть легко получать **часть** информации из *json*'а, по указанному пути. А также позволяет фильтровать по условию.

```
// Выведет все фамилии друзей
List<String> friendsLastnames = JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.friends[*].lastName");
for (String lastname : friendsLastnames) {
    System.out.println(lastname);
}

// output:
// Snow
// Tompson
```

Пример с выборкой по условию:

```
// Поиск друга, которому больше 22 лет
List<String> friendsWithAges = JsonPath
.using(Configuration.defaultConfiguration())
.parse(jsonString)
.read("$.friends[?(@.age > 22)].lastName", List.class);

for (String lastname : friendsWithAges) {
    System.out.println(lastname);
}

// output:  
// Tompson
```

Comment: У GSON также наличествует возможность менять поведение аннотациями

Comment: Понимаю, зачем ТС задал такой вопрос и сам же на него и ответил, ибо действительно достали вопросы новичков **как парсить Json**. Предлагаю ответ сделать общим и на вопросы по Json далее ставить дубли со ссылкой на этот ответ.

Comment: @Barmaley я бы предложил писать еще ответы, чтоб хотя бы ответ не был полотном гигантским. И еще хочу ЮрийСПб попросить чтоб отдельно написал ответы по Android, думаю там есть что-то тоже отдельно

Comment: @rjhdby добавил сий нюанс в ответ.

Comment: @Barmaley, для этого не надо ничего делать общим.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, спасибо, полезный ответ, но я всё равно уперся в один вопрос: А что делать если в json в объекте всё время разные пары ключ-значение? Я хочу их вогнать в свою модель данных, чтобы хранить и ключ и значение. HashMap не использую, потому что где то увидел , что его потом тяжело в listview выводить.

Comment: Ну как я понял для меня в ответах не хватает, то как выполнить что то такое Type type = new TypeToken<ModelData>(){}.getType();   и после наполнить.  Ну или Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Double>>(){}.getType();  Какие парсеры позволяют это сделать

Comment: в Jackson, Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);
jsonString, это Json ввиде стринга? и откуда берётся? Спасибо! Статья - огонь!

Comment: @ДенисКондратов да это строка (string). Браться может откуда угодна - после чтения из файла или БД или прилетать из клиента/API и т.д. Может даже просто хардкорная строка типа `"{\"name\": \"John\"}"`, т.е. `Person person = mapper.readValue("{\"name\": \"John\"}", Person.class);`

Comment: У меня вопрос, а если есть файл формата  json, как его конвертировать в стринг?

Answer (score 10):

#### Еще несколько вариантов

---

### LoganSquare

*LoganSquare* - основана на *Jackson*'s streaming API. По **[демонстрируемым тестам](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare/raw/development/docs/benchmarks.jpg)** работает быстрее *GSON* и *Jackson*. Поэтому хорош для Android.

**Где взять:** [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) / или через *Maven* / *Gradle* и пр.

**Использование:** https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare#usage

- Классы должны быть помечены аннотацией `@JsonObject`
- Поля должны быть помечены аннотацией `@JsonField` (с различными варианциями входных параметров, например `@JsonField(name="message")`)
- Другие предъявляемые требования: https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare/blob/development/docs/Models.md

Простенький пример:

```
@JsonObject
public class Person {
    @JsonField(name="firstName")
    public String firstName;
    @JsonField(name="age")
    public int age;

    public void say() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("My name is " + firstName + " , I'm " + age + " years old!");
    }
}
```

разбор:

```
String jsonString = "{\"age\":15,\"firstName\":\"Adam\"}";
Person person = LoganSquare.parse(jsonString, Person.class);
person.say(); // My name is Adam , I'm 18 years old!
```

---

### Moshi

> Moshi is a modern JSON library for Android and Java.

Хорош, как утверждают разработчики, для работы с Android.

**Где взять:** [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/square/moshi) / или через *Maven* / *Gradle* и пр.

- Пример разбора *Json* строки в объект `Person`:

  ```
  Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
  JsonAdapter<Person> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Person.class);
  Person person = jsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonStringPerson);  // В person будут все данные
  ```
- Пример парсинга в `Map`:

  ```
  class Seanse {
      public String name;
      public String locate
      public String metro;
      public List<Sessions> sessions;
  }

  class Sessions {
      public String time;
      public double price;
  }

  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
          String jsonStringForMap = "{\"2\":{\"sessions\":[{\"time\":\"13:00\",\"price\":\"410\"},{ \"time\":\"06:40\",\"price\":\"340\"},{  \"time\":\"16:50\",\"price\":\"370\"}],\"name\":\"Кинокис-L\",\"locate\":\"Москва, Садовая-Спасская ул., 21, 56\",\"metro\":\"Красные ворота\"},\"7\":{  \"sessions\":[  {  \"time\":\"06:35\",\"price\":\"190\"},{  \"time\":\"00:05\",\"price\":\"410\"}],\"name\":\"Кинокис-V\",\"locate\":\"Павелецкая пл., 2, строение 1\",\"metro\":\"Павелецкая\"},\"8\":{  \"sessions\":[  {  \"time\":\"15:10\",\"price\":\"330\"}],\"name\":\"Кинокис-J\",\"locate\":\"ул. Пречистенка, 40/2\",\"metro\":\"Кропоткинская\"},\"9\":{  \"sessions\":[  {  \"time\":\"13:00\",\"price\":\"600\"},{  \"time\":\"08:30\",\"price\":\"300\"},{  \"time\":\"04:00\",\"price\":\"510\"},{  \"time\":\"13:15\",\"price\":\"340\"}],\"name\":\"Кинокис-U\",\"locate\":\"Шарикоподшипниковская ул., 24\",\"metro\":\"Дубровка\"}}";

          Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
          Type map = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, Seanse.class);
          JsonAdapter<Map<String, Seanse>> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(map);
          Map<String, Seanse> seanseMap = jsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonStringForMap);
      }
  }
  ```

---

### Genson

**Где взять:** [здесь](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) / [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/owlike/genson) / или через *Maven* и пр.

**Документация:** http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/UserGuide/

За счет создания POJO (создаются классы, которые повторяют структуру *Json*'а) - парсится объект из строки, распихивая по нужным полям объектов. Есть возможность фильтровать свойства, включить или исключить поля при парсинге, 
переименовать, возможность работы с аннотациями и пр. Подробнее в документации.

- Простой парсинг:

  ```
  Genson genson = new Genson();
  Person person = genson.deserialize(jsonString, Person.class); // В person будут все данные
  ```
- Разбор в список:

  ```
  List<Object> persons = genson.deserialize("[{\"age\":28,\"name\":\"Foo\"}, {\"age\":30,\"name\":\"Bar\"}]", List.class);    
  // persons - список с данными объектов
  ```
- Пример парсинга в `Map`:

...... *JSON* для разбора:

```js
{  
 "2":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"13:00",
    "price":"410"
   },
   {  
    "time":"06:40",
    "price":"340"
   },
   {  
    "time":"16:50",
    "price":"370"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-L",
  "locate":"Москва, Садовая-Спасская ул., 21, 56",
  "metro":"Красные ворота"
 },
 "7":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"06:35",
    "price":"190"
   },
   {  
    "time":"00:05",
    "price":"410"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-V",
  "locate":"Павелецкая пл., 2, строение 1",
  "metro":"Павелецкая"
 },
 "8":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"15:10",
    "price":"330"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-J",
  "locate":"ул. Пречистенка, 40/2",
  "metro":"Кропоткинская"
 },
 "9":{  
  "sessions":[  
   {  
    "time":"13:00",
    "price":"600"
   },
   {  
    "time":"08:30",
    "price":"300"
   },
   {  
    "time":"04:00",
    "price":"510"
   },
   {  
    "time":"13:15",
    "price":"340"
   }
  ],
  "name":"Кинокис-U",
  "locate":"Шарикоподшипниковская ул., 24",
  "metro":"Дубровка"
 }
}
```

...... Классы (POJO):

```
class Seanse {
    public String name;
    public String locate
    public String metro;
    public List<Sessions> sessions;
}

class Sessions {
    public String time;
    public double price;
}
```

...... Сам парсинг:

```
String jsonStringForMap = "ТУТ JSON СТРОКА, ОПИСАННАЯ ВЫШЕ";
Genson genson = new Genson();
Map<String, Seanse> seansesMap = genson.deserialize(jsonStringForMap, Map.class);
```

---

### FastJson

**Где взять:** через *Maven* и другие сборщики / [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson). Непосредственно **[описание работы с xpath](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson/wiki/JSONPath)**. 
**Осторожно,**   ̶н̶е̶н̶о̶р̶м̶а̶т̶и̶в̶н̶а̶я̶ ̶л̶е̶к̶с̶и̶к̶а̶    китайский язык.

Относится к **XPath** аналогам.

Обычный способ:

```
Person person = JSON.parseObject(jsonString, Person.class);
int age = person.age;
System.out.println(age); // 30
```

Применение XPpath

```
// Выведет все фамилии друзей
List<String> friendsLastnames = (List<String>) JSONPath.eval(person, "$.friends.lastName");
for (String lastname : friendsLastnames) {
    System.out.println(lastname);  // Snow  Tompson
}

// Поиск друга, которому больше 22 лет
List<String> friendsWithAges = (List<String>) JSONPath.eval(person, "$.friends[?(@.age > 22)].lastName");
for (String lastname : friendsWithAges) {
    System.out.println(lastname); // Tompson
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### [JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp)

Поддерживает сериализацию и парсинг JSON без предварительного маппинга в классах:

**Maven:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Пример разбора строки JSON:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
    JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
}
```

**Пример вывода объекта в строку JSON:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(prettyPrintJson(jsonObject, 0));
}

public static String prettyPrintJson(JsonObject jsonObject, int indent) {

    String indentStr = getIndentStr(indent);
    String prettyJson = indentStr + "{";

    for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        prettyJson += "\n";
        prettyJson += indentStr + "  \"" + key + "\": ";
        try {
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.get(key).asJsonArray();
            prettyJson += "\n" + indentStr + "  [";
            for (JsonValue element : jsonArray) {
                prettyJson += "\n" + prettyPrintJson(element.asJsonObject(), indent + 4);
                prettyJson += ",";
            }
            prettyJson = prettyJson.substring(0, prettyJson.length() - 1);
            prettyJson += "\n" + indentStr + "  ]";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                prettyJson += "\n" + prettyPrintJson(jsonObject.get(key).asJsonObject(), indent + 2);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                prettyJson += jsonObject.get(key).toString();
            }
        }
        prettyJson += ",";
    }
    prettyJson = prettyJson.substring(0, prettyJson.length() - 1);
    prettyJson += "\n" + indentStr + "}";
    return prettyJson;
}

public static String getIndentStr(int indent) {
    String indentStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
        indentStr += " ";
    }
    return indentStr;
}
```

Вывод:

```json
{
  "firstName": "Json",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 30,
  "address":
  {
    "streetAddress": "666 1nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": 10021
  },
  "phoneNumbers":
  [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "542 666-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "fax",
      "number": "653 666-4567"
    }
  ],
  "friends":
  [
    {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Snow",
      "age": 20,
      "phoneNumbers":
      [
        {
          "type": "home",
          "number": "141 111-1234"
        }
      ],
      "friends":
      [
        {
          "firstName": "UnknownFirstName",
          "lastName": "UnknownLastName",
          "age": 999,
          "phoneNumbers":
          [
            {
              "type": "home",
              "number": "000 000-0000"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Flash",
      "lastName": "Tompson",
      "age": 23,
      "phoneNumbers":
      [
        {
          "type": "home",
          "number": "999 111-1234"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Поддерживает сериализацию и парсинг JSON без предварительного маппинга в классах` - потому что это ручной разбор, при котором разработчику известна структура и нужно писать велосипеды аналогично похожему  Simple Json  %)

Comment: Когда известна структура наверно можно посмотреть ещё один sjr specification номер 367 или json-b (json binding)

Answer (score 2):

Здесь расположена общая информация о парсерах, которая может помочь при выборе и понять, что он умеет. Текст и таблица, представленные ниже, взяты из публикации на *Habrahabr*: 
**[Шпаргалка Java программиста 8. Библиотеки для работы с Json](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/280782/)**, автор статьи **@ВеденинВячеслав**

> Существует следующие способы сериализации и десериализации среди
>   указанных библиотек (от самого простого к самому сложному):
>
> 1. Data bind
> 2. Tree Model
> 3. Streaming API
> 4. Аналоги XPath (дополнительный способ)
>
> ### Data bind
>
> Самый популярный и простой способ - вы просто указываете класс,
>   который нужно преобразовать в *json*, может быть часть полей отмечаете
>   аннотациями (а зачастую даже это необязательно), а библиотека сама
>   превращает этот класс и всю его иерархию классов в *json*.
>
> **Плюсы**: наиболее простой из всех
>
> **Минусы**: скорость и память. Большинство библиотек использует рефлексию и т.п. методы работы с *Java* классами (хотя не все), что
>   очевидно не очень быстро. К тому же, весь *json* файл сразу
>   превращается в *Java* объекты, что может просто исчерпать всю
>   доступную память, если вы попытаетесь обработать очень большой *json*.
>
> **Вывод**: если нет проблем с производительностью, памятью и вы не собираетесь обрабатывать многогигабайтные *json'ы* скорее всего самый
>   лучший способ.
>
> ---
>
> ### Tree Model
>
> Данный парсер представляет *json* в виде *Java* классов таких как
>   `Node` или `JsonElement c иерархической структурой, а уже сам
>   программист их обходит и получает из них информацию.
>
> **Плюсы**: обычно быстрее первого способа и проще третьего
>
> **Минусы**: уступает **Data bind** по простоте, плюс ряд библиотек способен генерить классы при **Data bind**, а не использовать
>   рефлексию, в этом случае то что **Tree Model** будет быстрее не
>   очевидно, к тому же не решается проблема огромных файлов и ограничения
>   памяти.
>
> ---
>
> ### Streaming API
>
> Самый низкоуровневый способ, по сути программист сам вручную разбирает
>   токены *json'a*. Зато никаких ограничений по памяти и в теории
>   максимальная производительность.
>
> **Плюсы**: производительность и минимальное потребление памяти
>
> **Минусы**: сложность использования
>
> ---
>
> ### Аналоги XPath
>
> Не очень подходит, если нужно получит **всю** информацию из *json*'a, зато
>   позволяет написав выражение, например `$.store.book[*].author`  получить список всех авторов всех книг из *json*'a магазина. То есть **легко** получать
>   **часть** информации из *json*'а.
>
> **Плюсы**: позволяет быстро получить информацию из *json*'а по сложным критериям
>
> **Минусы**: не очень подходит, когда нужна все информация из *json*'а, не работает в обратную сторону на формирования *json*'ов

---

Таблица библиотек и способы парсинга, которые они поддерживают:

```
Способ\Hазвание  Fastjson  Gson  LoganSquare  JSONjava  Moshi  Jackson  Genson  JsonPath SimpleJson

Data bind          Да       Да       Да         -        Да       Да      Да       -         -
Tree Model         -        Да       -          Да       -        Да      -        -         Да
Streaming API      -        Да       -          -        -        Да      -        -         -
Аналоги XPath      Да       -        -          -        -        -       -        Да        -

Генерация классов  -        -        Да         -        -        -       -        -
 для Data bind*

Работает со        Да       Да       Нет        -        Да       Да      Да       -
static inner class**

Обязательность     Нет      Нет      Да         -        Нет      Нет     Нет      -
 аннотаций***
```

* — Генерация классов для Data bind позволяет сгенерировать классы на стадии компиляции, что в теории должно давать значительный прирост производительности библиотеки,

** — Работает со static inner class имеет смысл только для случая Data bind, возможно ли сериализация и десериализация для случая статических внутренних классов (не статические внутренние классы сериализовать не рекомендуется),

*** — тоже только для случая Data bind можно ли не использовать аннотации или их использование крайне рекомендуется,