# вопросы по json парсингу

Tags: java, android, json

Есть ответ, в котором перечень валют с значениями. На случай если список валют увеличится, я в заранее хотел распарсить и сохранить массив валют. Но как я теперь понял, сперва узнается формат json , а потом под него строится java класс. Т.е. выходит что под каждый запрос создается своя структура java класса. А эта структура java класса и есть парсер ? Ведь вижу что в сети есть разные парсеры. Значит парсер это не структура класса. А чем тогда отличаются парсеры? 
  И есть ли такая практика, что делается такая логика, которая сперва получает json, потом списывает с него данные ?

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/Как-и-чем-парсить-json-на-java

Comment: Спасибо, полезная информация , годится как ответ.