# Как в Gson взять список?

Tags: java, gson

Добрый день у меня возникла проблема, я через jsoup взял json. Вот так

```
String data = Jsoup.connect("https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/"+config.twichID+"/chatters").ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

Но не могу понять теперь как преобразовать это в Gson и взять этот список.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094

Comment: А с чем собственно говоря проблемы?