# Как разобрать массив "Current Sales" и добавить его в ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, android, json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "Сafe #1",
    "Address": "New York",
    "Current Sales": [
      12.16,
      8.98,
      17.82,
      11.69,
      13.23,
      11.3,
      19.73,
      3.99,
      12.43,
      21.28,
      6.36,
      14.41,
      20.12,
      7.82
    ],
    "Sales Plan": 3900
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Сafe #2",
    "Address": "New York",
    "Current Sales": [
      18.51,
      12.59,
      9.52,
      7.29,
      17.25,
      22.78,
      5.36,
      12.73,
      19.04,
      2.74,
      6.27,
      9.43,
      8.84,
      16.27
    ],
    "Sales Plan": 3500
  }
]
```

Код

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

            mObjects = new ArrayList<>();
            Object object = new Object();
            object.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
            object.setName((String) jsonObject.get("Name"));
            object.setAddress((String) jsonObject.get("Address"));

            List<Object.Sales> currentSalesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j=0; j<jsonObject.getJSONArray("Current Sales").length(); j++) {
                Object.Sales sales = new Object.Sales();
                ......
            }
```

Comment: посмотрите в сторону библиотеки GSON или ей подобных. ваша задача сильно упростится

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Comment: самый правильный вариант в данном случае ↑