# Android studio GSON десериализация

Tags: java, android, gson

Привет, помогите сделать простую десериализацию, в чем ошибка?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "LOL";

    String jsons = "{'appname':'application', 'Version':'0.1.0', 'UUID':'300V', 'WWXY':'310W', 'ABCD':'270B', 'YUDE':'280T'}";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        MainActivity mainActivity = gson.fromJson(jsons, MainActivity.class);

        Log.i(TAG, "MSG " + mainActivity);


    }
}
```

Comment: Не надо задать тот же самый вопрос - редактируйте старый

Comment: Этак у вас 2 вопроса на одну проблему и оба неполны - в одном логи ошибки, а в другом - код.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на сколько мог заполнил: [Как-и-чем-парсить-json-на-java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/)  .... 9 вариантов и табличка-ориентир. Так что может в будущем помочь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, круто! Плюсанул там всё)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте класс-модель для json и парсите оный в эту модель:

```
public class MyPojo
{
    public String WWXY;

    public String appname;

    public String YUDE;

    public String UUID;

    public String ABCD;

    public String Version;
}
```

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyPojo data = gson.fromJson(jsons, MyPojo.class);
```

---

Больше информации о парсинге JSON тут - [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745095/17609)