# Перебор ключей JSONObject (библиотека org.json)

Tags: java, json

На сервер приходит jsonobject , с неизвестными ключами
например:`{"perviy":"1","2":"vtoroy","223dsds0":"adfad"}`
как вытянуть все ключи и соответствующие значения?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `HashMap`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать методы `keys()`, `keySet()`, `names()` у объекта `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

### [JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp)

Поддерживает сериализацию и парсинг JSON без предварительного маппинга в классах:

**Maven:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Пример разбора строки JSON:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
    JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
}
```