# Подскажите, как парсить этот JSON файл?

Tags: java, json, gson

Я использую Gson. Возникла проблема с `"aPoints"`. `"aTrack"` я парсил вот так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        System.out.println("Reading JSON from a file");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("H:file.json"));
        Country country = gson.fromJson(br, Country.class);
        System.out.println(country.getaTrack().getType());
        ...
```

JSON:

```
{
    "aWaypoints": [],
    "aTrack": {
        "type": "walk",
        "dt_start": "2016-08-10 15:51:36",
        "dt_end": "2016-08-10 15:56:26",
        "time": "289",
        "distance": "1113.8",
        "id_track": "36131",
        "sp_avg": "13.9",
        "sp_max": "16.7",
        "calories": "59.1",
        "description": null,
        "access": "1",
        "weight": "59",
        "cardio": "0",
        "hr_max": 0,
        "hr_avg": 0,
        "var_max": "0",
        "var_min": "0",
        "status": false
    },
    "id": "10",
    "aPoints": [
        [61.786379, 34.37813, 29, 1470833786, 0, 0, 88],
        [61.786389, 34.378115, 29.1, 1470833785, 0, 8.6, 104],
        [61.786389, 34.378115, 29.1, 1470833784, 0, 8.6, 104],
        [61.786395903507, 34.37808239104, 29, 1470833783, 0, 11.9, 108],
        [61.786406903507, 34.37798639104, 29.4, 1470833782, 0, 13.1, 128],
        [61.787004543635, 34.372654768507, 29.7, 1470833670, 0, 8.9, 82],
        [61.787004543635, 34.372654768507, 29.7, 1470833669, 0, 8.9, 82],
        [61.787001543635, 34.372612768507, 30, 1470833668, 0, 9, 82],
        [61.787008543635, 34.372573768507, 30.1, 1470833667, 0, 9.3, 83]
    ],
    "sMsg": "",
    "sMsgTitle": "",
    "bStateError": false,
    "min_id": null
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Comment: Какая именно проблема возникла с полем `aPoints`? И можете показать класс `Country`?

Comment: @rjhdby не совсем дубль. здесь уже используется Gson и есть проблема с конкретным полем, а не с парсингом вообще.

Comment: @AlexChermenin в том ответе есть примеры парсинга в List с помощью GSON, так что вполне

Comment: @AlexChermenin Вот класс Country `public class Country {
    public aTrack getaTrack() {
        return aTrack;
    }
    public void setaTrack(aTrack aTrack) {
        this.aTrack = aTrack;
    }
    private aTrack aTrack;
}`  вот класс aTrack `public class aTrack {
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }    public String getDt_start() {
        return dt_start;
    }private String type;private String dt_start;`

Comment: @AlexChermenin проблема с полем aPoints, я не могу сделать по аналогии с другими полями, потому что там массив массивов. В интернете не нашел пример, как распарсить массив массивов

Answer (score -2):

Рекомендую использовать библиотеку `Newtonson.Json`
Структура вашего JSON такая:

[image: JSON]