# Запись и получение данных json mysql

Tags: java, mysql, json

Есть таблица в mysql

```
id     name     text
```

Столбец text имеет тип JSON.
Получаю данные из этого столбца:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM texts WHERE `name`=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = MySQL.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, "name");
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
if(result.next()){
    text = result.getString("text");
}
```

Вопрос: как данные в переменной text преобразовать в объект Json для дальнейшей работы с ним?

Делаю так:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(text);
```

Idea выдает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Error:(59, 31) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Map

Comment: А можно ошибку текстом к вопросу прикрепить?

Comment: Error:(59, 31) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>

Comment: Ну, давайте тянуть информацию по частям... Увидеть бы исходный Json, который хранится в таблице или хотя бы его аналог.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
String s = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
```

и дальше работать с Object.

Если у вас не просто какой-то json, если его можно маппить на объект то Алексей Шиманский для вас все расписал в большом ответе

[Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094)