# Как забирать из содержимого (из ответа сервера) другой заголовок?

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

**Пытаюсь забрать адреса картинок с помощью данного класса:**

```
public class AlbumArtGrabber {

// ключ API
public final static String API_KEY = "******";
// ID поисковой системы
public final static String SEARCH_ENGINE = "*********";

private final static String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
// полный URL для поискового запроса
private final static String GET_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="
        + API_KEY + "&cx=" + SEARCH_ENGINE + "&q=";


public static List<URL> doGoogleSearch(final String query, int page) {

    if (query == null || query.trim().isEmpty() || page < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Ошибка: заданы некорректные аргументы.");
    }

    List<URL> result = new ArrayList<URL>();

    // заменяем все пробелы в поисковом запросе, если есть
    String searchQuery = query.replaceAll(" ", "+");

    System.out.println("Поиск начался.");

    try {
        // номер страцы результатов поиска Google
        String start = "&start=" + String.valueOf(page);
        // небходимо закодировать UTF-8 строку
        searchQuery = URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, ENCODING);

        URL url = new URL(GET_URL + searchQuery + start + "&alt=json&");
        // выполняем GET запрос и получаем список ссылок
        // из результатов поиска
        result.addAll(getListOfUrlsFormGoogleResponse(url));

        System.out.println("Поиск завершен");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Во время поиска произошла ошибка: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}


private static List<URL> getListOfUrlsFormGoogleResponse(final URL url)
        throws ProtocolException, IOException {

    List<URL> result = new ArrayList<URL>();

    // создаем соединение
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // заголовоки GET запроса
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

    System.out.println("Строка поискового запроса: " + url.toString());
    System.out.println("Ответ от сервера: ");

    // ответ от сервера
    // в ответе содержится различная информация, однако нам необходимо
    // получить
    // только URL

    String output;

    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(output);

        final String PARAM = "\"link\": \"";

        // берем из ответа только ссылку и добавляем ее в результат
        if (output.contains(PARAM)) {
            String link = output.substring(
                    output.indexOf(PARAM) + (PARAM).length(),
                    output.indexOf("\","));

            result.add(new URL(link));
        }
    }

    //закрываем сетевое соединение
    conn.disconnect();

    return result;
}}
```

**Получаю ответ такого вида:**

```
{
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Astronomy Picture of the Day",
   "htmlTitle": "Astronomy Picture of the Day",
   "link": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html",
   "displayLink": "apod.nasa.gov",
   "snippet": "Explanation: Normally faint and elusive, the Jellyfish Nebula is caught in this \nalluring telescopic image. Centered in the scene it's anchored right and left by \ntwo bright stars, Mu and Eta Geminorum, at the foot of the celestial twin. The \nJellyfish Nebula is the brighter arcing ridge of emission with dangling tentacles. \nIn fact, the ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Explanation: Normally faint and elusive, the Jellyfish Nebula is caught in this \u003cbr\u003e\nalluring telescopic \u003cb\u003eimage\u003c/b\u003e. Centered in the scene it&#39;s anchored right and left by \u003cbr\u003e\ntwo bright stars, Mu and Eta Geminorum, at the foot of the celestial twin. The \u003cbr\u003e\nJellyfish Nebula is the brighter arcing ridge of emission with dangling tentacles. \u003cbr\u003e\nIn fact, the&nbsp;...",
   "cacheId": "87TgjKwQQIYJ",
   "formattedUrl": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html",
   "pagemap": {
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "276",
      "height": "182",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRe-lmsRxetMUTlcce6X6Kk2pM7o20HVyLAMHK_qwyQcJCNiwcmYJQ0yZE"
     }
    ],
    "metatags": [
     {
      "orgcode": "661",
      "rno": "phillip.a.newman",
      "content-owner": "Jerry.T.Bonnell.1",
      "webmaster": "Stephen.F.Fantasia.1",
      "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
     }
    ],
    "cse_image": [
     {
      "src": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1803/IC443_HaRGB1024.jpg"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
```

И окончательный результат, - я забираю из ответа только ссылки (заголовок link):

```
Поиск завершен
Список ссылок из результатов поиска:
https://vk.com/kartinka_da
https://translate.yandex.ru/ocr
https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=ru
http://bipbap.ru/category/krasivye-kartinki
http://tilda.education/articles-images-for-social
https://www.1zoom.ru/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C/t2/1/
http://www.astronet.ru/db/apod.html
https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html
https://www.livejournal.com/support/faq/6.html
http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2017/dark/

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Вопрос. Как забрать другое содержимое заголовков? Нужно брать не **link** а **src** из ответа.
например забрать из ответа такую строчку с заголовком `src` :

```
"src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRe-lmsRxetMUTlcce6X6Kk2pM7o20HVyLAMHK_qwyQcJCNiwcmYJQ0yZE"
```

Comment: Замена пробелов плюсами — это полная дичь. Есть куча других запрещённых символов. HTTP-клиенты (OkHttp, Volley) имеют встроенные билдеры URLов, не нужно собирать адреса руками.
Аналогично, есть JSON-парсеры — Gson, Moshi — так что не нужно парсить JSON регулярками.

Comment: Уже в явке появился `Json` - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject oj=new JSONObject("Тут ваш json код");     
JSONObject jso=new JSONObject();
            try {
                jso=oj.getJSONObject("pagemap");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(jso.getString("cse_image"));
                JSONObject tttt=ar.getJSONObject(0);
                String src=tttt.getString("src");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Я тут уже вернул строчку без "src":, но по желанию можете оставить так как у вас убрав строчку.

```
 String src=tttt.getString("src");
```

[image: Возврат]

В данном случае я вернул из cse_image, и на скриншоте url из него же, но вы можете заменив в моем коде "cse_image" на "cse_thumbnail" получить то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Просто выбирать аттрибут игнорируя структуру ответа скорее всего будет делать не то что вы ожидаете, а именно, в вашем примере

> ```
> "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRe-lmsRxetMUTlcce6X6Kk2pM7o20HVyLAMHK_qwyQcJCNiwcmYJQ0yZE"
> ```

вы получаете не картинку а ее тамбнейл, адрес же самой картинке из вашего примера находится в

> ```
> "cse_image": [
>  {
>   "src": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1803/IC443_HaRGB1024.jpg"
>  }
> ]
> ```

если нет экстремальных требований к производительности, я бы просто парсил ответ из json в объекты, а потом выбирал бы что надо.

как и чем парсить хорошо описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java)