# Android Java перебор (Ключи ассоциативного массива )

Tags: java, android, массивы, json, перебор

Я только начал погружение в java и android .
У меня есть код который мне спарсил json массив, но у меня не получается вывести ключи и их значения.

Вот код json

---

[image: ``]

---

и код моего парсера

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        //JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("employees");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("raspisanie");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject listData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                           String dataPar = listData.getString("today");
                            String cabsPar = listData.getString("cabs");
                           String[] testArray = new String[] {dataPar};



                            mTextViewResult.append(testArray + "\n\n");
                            mTextViewResult.append(cabsPar + "\n\n");



                           // mTextViewResult.append( dataPar + "\n\n");


                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

---

максимум что смог получить 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Забыл написать .
Вопрос решил , если надо то пиши на почту kip.vader@ya.ru

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)