# Регулярное выражение Java для html тегов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу найти слова в строке с помощью регулярки. Пробовала вот так:

```
Pattern d = Pattern.compile("(?<=(<th class=\"plainlist\")(.>)) 
([\\s\\S]*)(?=<\\/th>)");
```

Строка вот такая:

```
<th class="plainlist" style="min-width:9em; background:#eaecf0; 
vertical-align:top; padding-left:.5em; padding-right:.5em;">Род 
деятельности</th><th class="plainlist" style="min-width:9em; 
background:#eaecf0; vertical-align:top; padding-left:.5em; padding- 
right:.5em;">Язык произведений</th> 
<td class="plainlist">
<span class="no-wikidata" data-wikidata-property- 
id="P1412">русский</span></td>
</tr>
```

Нужно, чтобы вывело просто два слова: род деятельности

Моя регулярка исключает теги, но не их внутренности в скобках. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Что я делаю не так? Нужно, чтобы регулярка находила только то, что в тегах th.

Comment: (?<=>)[^<]+(?=<)

Comment: В тексте помимо тега th, есть и другие теги. Наверное, я неправильно описала задачу, но нужно, чтобы нашел только то, что в тегах th и вычленил из них текст. Сейчас переделаю описание.

Comment: Тогда (?<=>)[^<]+(?=<\/th) (в приведенном примере будет 2 совпадения т.к. тега th 2)

Comment: [Регулярки не годятся для парсинга `html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3212712). Используйте специальные библиотеки для этого.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, для dotnet нашёл [ответ с рекомендациями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/178576), который можно использовать для закрытия подобных вопросов как дубликатов. а для java подобного ответа что-то не вижу. надо бы написать. ну или клич кинуть, ведь знатоков java более чем достаточно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ого, для `.Net` очень крутой ответ) Для `Java` да, я такого не видел... Сам бы написал, коли время бы было) Может вы на мете вопрос поднимите? Авось и найдутся желающие ответ хороший накатать как было, например, для `json`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745095/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добрый день! Я бы с радостью, но задание было написать именно регулярку, к сожалению.

Comment: @JavaJunior добрый день! Спасибо большое за ответ, смогла на базе вашего решения придумать свою регулярку. Вы подсказали мне замечательную идею - ориентироваться по закрывающему тегу. Очень вас благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее регулярное выражение:

```
'<th[^>]+\\>([^<]+)\\<\\/th>'
```

[См. пример использования этого выражения](http://tpcg.io/3aUXop).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<th[^>]+\\>([^<]+)\\<\\/th>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html); // html - ваша html-строка

System.out.println(m.find() ? m.group(1) : "no match");
```