# Как присвоить значение переменной из файла. А переменная - object

Tags: java

Мне нужно допустим перекачать объект класса Example в файл и потом из файла его восстановить и присвоить обратно

Comment: Возможно вам подойдёт запись в виде JSON и обратное чтение из JSON в объект класса. Но это не точно, т.к. то, что вы описываете можно понять несколькими десятками способов. Наверное, вы получите нужный вам ответ, если опишите какую задачу решаете.

Comment: В моём классе содержаться ещё классы и я хочу их хранить в JSON, но в интернете не нашёл

Comment: Разбейте задачу на части. Например такие: 1. Как класс преобразовать в JSON строку. 2. Как строку записать в файл. 3. Как считать файл в строку. 4. Как строку с JSON преобразовать в экземпляр Java класса. По этим вопросам в сети всё есть. по п.1 смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример сериализации класса в файл

```
            MyClass myClassVariable = new MyClass(<параметры>);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objectOut.writeObject(myClassVariable);
            objectOut.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
```