# Конвертация string в json

Tags: java, json

К примеру у меня есть строка String

```
[{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.455499","street":{"id":943348,"name":"On or near Cortis Road"},"longitude":"-0.230576"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614959,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.455499","street":{"id":943348,"name":"On or near Cortis Road"},"longitude":"-0.230576"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614960,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.465410","street":{"id":943224,"name":"On or near Dryburgh Road"},"longitude":"-0.230654"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614961,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.465410","street":{"id":943224,"name":"On or near Dryburgh Road"},"longitude":"-0.230654"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614962,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.464231","street":{"id":943220,"name":"On or near Fairdale Gardens"},"longitude":"-0.232384"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614964,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.462317","street":{"id":943387,"name":"On or near Woodborough Road"},"longitude":"-0.234890"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614966,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.456707","street":{"id":943421,"name":"On or near Torwood Road"},"longitude":"-0.239152"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614970,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.452980","street":{"id":939210,"name":"On or near Bader Way"},"longitude":"-0.242490"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614978,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.458789","street":{"id":943394,"name":"On or near Roehampton Lane"},"longitude":"-0.243044"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614979,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.458789","street":{"id":943394,"name":"On or near Roehampton Lane"},"longitude":"-0.243044"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614980,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.463408","street":{"id":943373,"name":"On or near Rockingham Close"},"longitude":"-0.250079"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614987,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.480419","street":{"id":945018,"name":"On or near Atherton Road"},"longitude":"-0.242689"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62616824,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.464530","street":{"id":943380,"name":"On or near Arabella Drive"},"longitude":"-0.251174"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62614991,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.477290","street":{"id":945017,"name":"On or near Baronsmead Road"},"longitude":"-0.239684"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62616823,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.465354","street":{"id":943388,"name":"On or near Warwick Drive"},"longitude":"-0.235954"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62616821,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},{"category":"anti-social-behaviour","location_type":"Force","location":{"latitude":"51.478126","street":{"id":945015,"name":"On or near Berkeley Road"},"longitude":"-0.242705"},"context":"","outcome_status":null,"persistent_id":"","id":62616825,"location_subtype":"","month":"2018-01"},
```

и тд, нужно ее разборать на json объекты и занести их в массив, в котором уже в дальнейшем из них будут получаться нужные данные и заноситься в бд. Как разобрать строку на json объекты и занести их в массив? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: На данный вопрос уже есть ответ
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/Как-и-чем-парсить-json-на-java

Comment: да, но вопрос остался прежним, если все в одной строке, то как поочередно запарсить все, и дбоавить в массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример с **Jackson** и массивом:

```java
package click.webelement.json;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ArrayTest {

    final static String JSON = "[{\"name\": \"John\"}, {\"name\": \"Jack\"}]";

    static class Person{

        public String name;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Person[] persons = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON, Person[].class);
        System.out.println("Stop here");
    }

}
```

Дебаг показывает, что массив корректно распаршен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** - "статичность" класса `Person` нужна, чтобы конкретно этот пример работал, потому как Jackson специфично работает с inner-классами. `System.out` нужен, чтобы было за что зацепиться дебагером.