# Как сохранять ListView с множественным выбором в SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

В своем андроид-приложении я использую ListView с множественным выбором (multiplyChoice). Могу ли я сохранять выбранные элементы в SharedPreferences после выхода из приложения и затем восстанавливать их оттуда.

Comment: Да, можете. Если что то не получается-уточните вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это конвертировать в json
В результате у вас должно получиться что-то вроде этого и эту строку вы можете сохранить в sharedpreferences

{"id":"0","choices":{"choice_one":"abc","choice_two":"bbc"}},{"id":"1","choices":{"choice_one":"abc","choice_two":"bbc"}},{"id":"2","choices":{"choice_one":"abc","choice_two":"bbc"}}

Для этого вам нужно будет создать класс а потом список из этих классов преобразовать в json

Вот есть развернутый ответ по этому поводу:
[Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java)