# Преобразование из String в объект класса внутри метода onMessage в WebSocketListener в OkHttp3

Tags: android, json, kotlin, websocket, okhttp

Всем привет! Реализую свой WebSocketListener, и задался вопросом: в метод onMessage мне приходит тип данных String. С сервера поступает JSON строка, то есть, получается, она и приходит. У меня вопрос: как можно эту полученную строку без лишних усилий преобразовать в экземпляр класса? (точнее, как ПРАВИЛЬНО её преобразовать)?

Comment: Можно. Для этого есть специальные библиотеки. Посмотрите вот этот вопрос с ответом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java

Comment: Для [tag:kotlin] лучше всего либа `Moshi` подойдёт.

Comment: причем Moshi делают теже люди, что okhttp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это в зависимости

```
//moshi
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2"
kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2'
```

Это класс

```
  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Message(
    @Json(name = "id") val id:Long,
    @Json(name = "text")val text:String,
    @Json(name = "dateTime") val dataTime:String,
    @Json(name = "user") val user: User,
    @Json(name = "sendId")val sendId: Long? = null
) : Serializable
```

это создание адаптера

```
fun moshi():Moshi
{
    return Moshi.Builder().build()
}

  
fun adapterPostMessage(): JsonAdapter<Message>
{
    return moshi().adapter(Message::class.java)
}
```

Это парсер в обьект

```
 override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
        Log.d(TAG,"Message ${text}")
     
       val message = adapter.fromJson(text)!!
       updateList(message)
       
    }
```

Надеюсь не смутит что Kotlin, но надеюсь и так понятно