# Парсинг файла при помощи Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

На эту тему задано много вопросов, но спустя продолжительное время я так и не смог решить проблему.
Вот маленький кусочек кода при работе с библиотекой GSON. Он взят из статьи [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java) .

В этой статье приведён пример Json и варианты как его распарсить. Я выбрал GSON, но у меня json хранится в файле на компьютере и я не понимаю как передать этот файл парсеру GSON.
Ниже в коде на месте переменной way я так понимаю должен быть путь к файлу или url?
Я сделал всё как в статье создал классы повторяющие структуру данных, но у меня выдаёт ошибку.
В самом низу пикча для полноты картины. Расширение файла там указано txt, но менял и на json такая же проблема.

```
Gson g = new Gson();
    Person person = g.fromJson(way, Person.class);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код не стоит постить в виде скриншота - можете так нарваться на грубость...

Comment: Я не хотел постить код в картинке, только ошибки хотел показать, думал так будет понятней, но спасибо за замечание.

Comment: попробуйте пользоваться поисковиком. на стеке полно ответов и примеров на эту тему. лично я уже отвечал на подобные вопросы не один раз, причем последний буквально день назад с примером кода : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237252/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-arraylist

Comment: @OlgaMechnekova стек ошибки тоже можно спокойно скопировать и запостить

Comment: @Barmaley понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
String way = "путь к файлу";
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(way));

Gson gson = new Gson();
Person person = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, Person.class);
```