# Как разобрать JSON в Java

Tags: java, android, json

работаю со следующим API
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=55&lon=45&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=ae6c88286b0cb8936d10a31a4f2a44e4
Как можно получить повторяющийся temp ? Когда создаю JSONJbject получается захватить только самый первый.

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки в коде - подскжем что и где не так. Так же покажите JSON который призодит с сервера текстом прямо в вопросе. Без этой информации помочь можем лишь стеной текста с общими соображениями по парсингу вообще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю вам нужно получить `daily` как `JsonArray` и дальше работать с ним. Потом, как доберетесь до `temp` получать его как `JsonObject`, далее можно будет вытащить любое значение на выбор (см. комментарии в коде)

Вот пример, получение даты и температуры всех дней из ответа:
(я добавил `units=metric` чтобы получать данные в градусах Цельсия, можете убрать, если не нужно)

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        URL url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=55&lon=45&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=ae6c88286b0cb8936d10a31a4f2a44e4");
        BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        JsonObject rootJsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonObject.class);

        for (JsonElement dailyInfoElement : rootJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("daily")) {
            JsonObject dailyInfo = dailyInfoElement.getAsJsonObject();

            Date dateOfDay = new Date(dailyInfo.get("dt").getAsLong() * 1000L);
            JsonObject temperatures = dailyInfo.getAsJsonObject("temp");

            System.out.printf("Temperature at day [%s] is %.2f%n%n", dateOfDay, temperatures.get("day").getAsFloat());
            // You can also use values ["day", "min", "max", "night", "eve", "morn"] in temperatures.get()
        }
        
        jsonReader.close();
    }
}
```

*OUT:*

```
Temperature at day [Fri Feb 05 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -5,00

Temperature at day [Sat Feb 06 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -17,76

Temperature at day [Sun Feb 07 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -19,49

Temperature at day [Mon Feb 08 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -25,63

Temperature at day [Tue Feb 09 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -25,08

Temperature at day [Wed Feb 10 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -24,09

Temperature at day [Thu Feb 11 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -24,45

Temperature at day [Fri Feb 12 12:00:00 MSK 2021] is -26,55
```