# Как распарсить данный JSON с помощью GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{
    "error": false,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "lastChecked": "2021-06-14T11:52:01.945Z",
        "covid19Stats": [
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Adygea Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Adygea Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 14782,
                "deaths": 216,
                "recovered": 14268
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Altai Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Altai Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 52410,
                "deaths": 2362,
                "recovered": 47075
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Altai Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Altai Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 17320,
                "deaths": 247,
                "recovered": 16806
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Amur Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Amur Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 23045,
                "deaths": 296,
                "recovered": 22389
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Arkhangelsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Arkhangelsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 64715,
                "deaths": 1008,
                "recovered": 62086
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Astrakhan Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Astrakhan Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 34804,
                "deaths": 805,
                "recovered": 33505
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Bashkortostan Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Bashkortostan Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 39378,
                "deaths": 540,
                "recovered": 37349
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Belgorod Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Belgorod Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 39579,
                "deaths": 716,
                "recovered": 37425
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Bryansk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Bryansk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 41359,
                "deaths": 376,
                "recovered": 40366
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Buryatia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Buryatia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 39924,
                "deaths": 951,
                "recovered": 38607
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Chechen Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Chechen Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 12426,
                "deaths": 140,
                "recovered": 12161
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Chelyabinsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Chelyabinsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 62944,
                "deaths": 1713,
                "recovered": 59006
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Chukotka Autonomous Okrug",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Chukotka Autonomous Okrug, Russia",
                "confirmed": 777,
                "deaths": 8,
                "recovered": 743
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Chuvashia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Chuvashia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 26386,
                "deaths": 1472,
                "recovered": 24157
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Dagestan Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Dagestan Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 34256,
                "deaths": 1505,
                "recovered": 31686
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Ingushetia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Ingushetia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 15920,
                "deaths": 190,
                "recovered": 15564
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Irkutsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Irkutsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 71326,
                "deaths": 2541,
                "recovered": 68213
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Ivanovo Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Ivanovo Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 37037,
                "deaths": 1242,
                "recovered": 35051
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Jewish Autonomous Okrug",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Jewish Autonomous Okrug, Russia",
                "confirmed": 4552,
                "deaths": 144,
                "recovered": 4334
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kabardino-Balkarian Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kabardino-Balkarian Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 24500,
                "deaths": 478,
                "recovered": 23770
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kaliningrad Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kaliningrad Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 34384,
                "deaths": 516,
                "recovered": 33230
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kalmykia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kalmykia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 21049,
                "deaths": 390,
                "recovered": 20377
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kaluga Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kaluga Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 36319,
                "deaths": 349,
                "recovered": 34721
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kamchatka Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kamchatka Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 14826,
                "deaths": 238,
                "recovered": 14087
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Karachay-Cherkess Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Karachay-Cherkess Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 20605,
                "deaths": 159,
                "recovered": 20255
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Karelia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Karelia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 48044,
                "deaths": 581,
                "recovered": 46334
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kemerovo Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kemerovo Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 37783,
                "deaths": 748,
                "recovered": 36492
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Khabarovsk Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Khabarovsk Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 53309,
                "deaths": 435,
                "recovered": 51128
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Khakassia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Khakassia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 23593,
                "deaths": 563,
                "recovered": 22509
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Khanty-Mansi Autonomous Okrug",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Khanty-Mansi Autonomous Okrug, Russia",
                "confirmed": 58275,
                "deaths": 801,
                "recovered": 56788
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kirov Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kirov Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 44811,
                "deaths": 375,
                "recovered": 42321
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Komi Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Komi Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 44635,
                "deaths": 968,
                "recovered": 43531
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kostroma Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kostroma Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 21976,
                "deaths": 498,
                "recovered": 19232
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Krasnodar Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Krasnodar Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 49701,
                "deaths": 3175,
                "recovered": 44447
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Krasnoyarsk Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Krasnoyarsk Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 74810,
                "deaths": 3826,
                "recovered": 68706
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kurgan Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kurgan Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 21771,
                "deaths": 431,
                "recovered": 20813
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Kursk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Kursk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 39251,
                "deaths": 866,
                "recovered": 37630
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Leningrad Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Leningrad Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 46455,
                "deaths": 1586,
                "recovered": 43497
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Lipetsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Lipetsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 32390,
                "deaths": 811,
                "recovered": 29444
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Magadan Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Magadan Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 8527,
                "deaths": 112,
                "recovered": 8317
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Mari El Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Mari El Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 13805,
                "deaths": 264,
                "recovered": 13303
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Mordovia Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Mordovia Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 21337,
                "deaths": 300,
                "recovered": 19012
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Moscow",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Moscow, Russia",
                "confirmed": 1234717,
                "deaths": 20907,
                "recovered": 1093738
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Moscow Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Moscow Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 281621,
                "deaths": 6267,
                "recovered": 232459
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Murmansk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Murmansk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 52039,
                "deaths": 1243,
                "recovered": 48617
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Nenets Autonomous Okrug",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Nenets Autonomous Okrug, Russia",
                "confirmed": 1127,
                "deaths": 4,
                "recovered": 1106
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Nizhny Novgorod Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Nizhny Novgorod Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 120242,
                "deaths": 3837,
                "recovered": 114049
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "North Ossetia - Alania Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "North Ossetia - Alania Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 17113,
                "deaths": 222,
                "recovered": 16440
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Novgorod Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Novgorod Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 31433,
                "deaths": 182,
                "recovered": 30612
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Novosibirsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Novosibirsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 44477,
                "deaths": 1943,
                "recovered": 40185
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Omsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Omsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 48399,
                "deaths": 1453,
                "recovered": 45999
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Stavropol Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Stavropol Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 55602,
                "deaths": 1579,
                "recovered": 52810
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Sverdlovsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Sverdlovsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 90704,
                "deaths": 3585,
                "recovered": 84601
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Tambov Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Tambov Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 33618,
                "deaths": 566,
                "recovered": 31963
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Tatarstan Republic",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Tatarstan Republic, Russia",
                "confirmed": 21878,
                "deaths": 514,
                "recovered": 19311
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Tomsk Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Tomsk Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 33281,
                "deaths": 447,
                "recovered": 31921
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Tula Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Tula Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 40854,
                "deaths": 2109,
                "recovered": 38261
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Tver Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Tver Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 43185,
                "deaths": 1118,
                "recovered": 40508
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Voronezh Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Voronezh Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 86857,
                "deaths": 3096,
                "recovered": 82239
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Yamalo-Nenets Autonomous Okrug",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Yamalo-Nenets Autonomous Okrug, Russia",
                "confirmed": 39390,
                "deaths": 422,
                "recovered": 38304
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Yaroslavl Oblast",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Yaroslavl Oblast, Russia",
                "confirmed": 42086,
                "deaths": 645,
                "recovered": 39983
            },
            {
                "city": null,
                "province": "Zabaykalsky Krai",
                "country": "Russia",
                "lastUpdate": "2021-06-14T04:22:46+00:00",
                "keyId": "Zabaykalsky Krai, Russia",
                "confirmed": 43983,
                "deaths": 686,
                "recovered": 41995
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Вот такие классы

```java
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Boolean error;
    @SerializedName("statusCode")
    @Expose
    private Integer statusCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Data data;

    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

public class Data {

    @SerializedName("lastChecked")
    @Expose
    private String lastChecked;
    @SerializedName("covid19Stats")
    @Expose
    private List<Covid19Stat> covid19Stats = null;

    public String getLastChecked() {
        return lastChecked;
    }

    public void setLastChecked(String lastChecked) {
        this.lastChecked = lastChecked;
    }

    public List<Covid19Stat> getCovid19Stats() {
        return covid19Stats;
    }

    public void setCovid19Stats(List<Covid19Stat> covid19Stats) {
        this.covid19Stats = covid19Stats;
    }

}


public class Covid19Stat {

    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private Object city;
    @SerializedName("province")
    @Expose
    private String province;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("lastUpdate")
    @Expose
    private String lastUpdate;
    @SerializedName("keyId")
    @Expose
    private String keyId;
    @SerializedName("confirmed")
    @Expose
    private Integer confirmed;
    @SerializedName("deaths")
    @Expose
    private Integer deaths;
    @SerializedName("recovered")
    @Expose
    private Integer recovered;

    public Object getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(Object city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getKeyId() {
        return keyId;
    }

    public void setKeyId(String keyId) {
        this.keyId = keyId;
    }

    public Integer getConfirmed() {
        return confirmed;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(Integer confirmed) {
        this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    public Integer getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    public void setDeaths(Integer deaths) {
        this.deaths = deaths;
    }

    public Integer getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    public void setRecovered(Integer recovered) {
        this.recovered = recovered;
    }

}
```

Вот так сейчас выглядит десериализация в конечном итоге

```java
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Example example =g.fromJson(response.body(),Example.class);
```

---

Разобрался, большое спасибо ЮрийСПб и AlekseiGaile

Comment: А в чём у вас конкретно проблема? Есть онлайн сервисы, которые JSON сконвертируют в классы, например. Да и без них тут не должно возникать проблем - достаточно 3 классов. 1-ый будет содержать второй, а во втором будет массив третьих классов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб проблема в том, что я хотел сделать по аналогии с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java), но у меня не получилось. А онлайн-сервисы - только от вас узнал, спасибо, но я хотел бы сделать по уму

Comment: Покажите как вы пробовали и что получилось - поможем исправить ошибки, если они есть)

Comment: Обновил основной текст

Comment: В целом похоже на правду. А вот что у вас после создания Gson происходит - не очень ясно. Судя по всему - попытка получить данные из тела ответа из сети. И, кажется, вы это делаете неправильно. Не знаю какая у вас библиотека используется, но, возможно, вам надо тело ответа в виде строки получить (типа `response.body().string()`), сохранить в переменную (т.к. второй раз оно может быть для чтения уже недоступно) и парсить именно строку из переменной.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, можете еще подсказать, как вывести например все названия областей, то есть проверить, точно ли отпарсилось или нет

Comment: Т.е. работает? Коли так, то просто в цикле выведите в консоль. Типа так: `for(covid19Stats Covid19Stats: example.data.Covid19Stats) { System.out.println("province: "+Covid19Stats.province); }`. И вам обязательно надо поправить именование - классы с большой, переменные с маленькой буквы. И уберите `static` - он тут не нужен и, скорее всего, всё напрочь ломает.

Comment: Нет, не работает, следующая ошибка - Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

static везде убрал, перепроверил типы данных
P.S. я использую для получения строки java.net.http

Comment: Парсится неправильно. Попробуйте локализовать проблему убирая переменные в классах пока не перестанет падать.

Comment: Теперь парсится правильно, но в классах как будто нет значений, из-за нехватки времени воспользовался сайтом json2pojo, там сгенерировалось с сеттерами и геттерами. Сейчас обновлю полностью как сейчас выглядит

Comment: Обновил классы и десериализацию

Comment: Сообразил, не пустые, я просто объявления перепутал, покажите пожалуйста для этого примера как вывести что-нибудь в строку

Comment: Не очень понятно что значит "не пустые, я просто объявления перепутал". Также, возможно, у вас тут не верно - `response.body()` (хотя хз - мы не знаем что такое `response`). Возможно, вам надо написать `response.body().string()`

Comment: я просто новый класс создал, но забыл что уже созданный есть. response.body - это верно(я с помощью java.net.http с API брал всю эту строку JSON), string не обязательно, я смог вызвать из этого только statuscode, а как мне вызвать там названия областей - я еще не понял.

Comment: Какой тип у `body()`?

Comment: Я не знаю, зачем вам эта информация, но [вот](https://ibb.co/9tPBsWB) что такое response.body(), насколько я понял - успешно все распарсилось, мне просто осталось понять, как теперь достать данные например название областей, и собственно числа смертей

Comment: По ссылке неизвестно куда я не пойду) Информация эта мне нужна чтобы понять вашу проблему. У меня есть подозрение, что вам надо что-то типа `example.getData().getCovid19Stats().get(0).getDeaths()`, но мне это представляется слишком простым, засим я и хочу выяснить в чём именно у вас проблема.

Comment: По ссылке просто фотохостинг, где собственно и показан код как получается response.body(), и никаких преступных целей я не преследую, собственно как и не ставлю вас в обратном переубедить, чего мне не удастся скорее всего, но если вам угодно - могу опубликовать здесь. Как я уже говорил - она просто получает строку с API. Проблема у меня лишь в том, что из-за скудоумия в Java я не знаю как получить данные из листов и прочего. А так вроде теперь я разобрался, как парсить и прочее, ошибку исправил. Спасибо вам за это.

Comment: А так да, мне надо что-то типа того, что вы написали.

Comment: Рад был помочь, коли помог)

Answer (score 0):

Уберите static из полей, добавьте сеттеры и геттеры, List Covid19Stats должен быть с маленькой буквы сovid19Stats
и все получится.

Comment: сделал, но зачем сеттеры и геттеры? если в том примере, который я указал в других комментариях без них?

Comment: @DenisLoktev обычно все таки требуются, опять таки вы в дальнейшем собираетесь как то работать с этим классом. В данном случае да, они излишни.