# Как распарсить Json на Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx-serialization

Какие есть способы распарсить Json?

```json
{
  "name": "Json Smith",
  "age": 30,
  "phones": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "542 666-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "fax",
      "number": "653 666-4567"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Котлин не умеет парсить json "из коробки". Используйте библиотеки: gson, jackson, kotlinx.serialization.

Comment: Для котлин можно использовать все те же самые библиотеки, что и для java. Вот тут [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745095) как использовать каждую. Котлин-специфичные решения это в первую очередь [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) от создателей языка, а также множество [других](https://kotlin.link/?q=json) библиотек.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы распарсить Json на Kotlin, вы можете взять [любую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745094) соответствующую библиотеку на Java. Но разные Java-библиотеки с разной степенью удобства ложатся на язык Kotlin.

Поэтому, кроме Java-библиотек, есть [kotlinx.serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html) — официальная библиотека от JetBrains, написанная на языке Kotlin.

Чтобы начать ей пользоваться, необходимо подключить плагин для Gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "[версия котлин]"
}
```

И добавить зависимость для сериализации Json:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:[версия]")
}
```

Далее, отметить все dto-классы аннотацией `@Serializable`:

```kotlin
@Serializable
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val phones: List<Phone>)

@Serializable
class Phone(val type: String, val number: String)
```

Теперь, чтобы распарсить Json из строки достаточно выполнить:

```kotlin
val person = Json.decodeFromString<Person>(jsonString)
```