# Как парсить JSON

Tags: java, android, gson

Мне необходимо из моего JSON взять только названия песен из songs. Подскажите как сделать это в этом JSON файле(исходник на JSON хранится здесь(http://myradio24.com/users/85276/status.json). Я попытался его отформатировать, но это мой первый опыт с JSON):

```json
"playlist":"\/",
"streams":[
  {
     "mount":"85276",
     "user":"85276",
     "kbps":128,
     "format":"mp3",
     "url":"https:\/\/myradio24.org\/85276"
  }
],
"rank":[
  [
     "admin",
     0,
     0,
     0,
     "img\/noavatar.jpg"
  ]
],
"songs":[
  [
     "13:36:27",
     "Goro-Road",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     3628123713
  ],
  [
     "13:38:38",
     "PAVELB4H-\u041c\u043d\u0435 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442 \u0431\u044b-kissvk.com",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     2278055077
  ],
  [
     "13:40:50",
     "BRANYA- MACAN-\u041f\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u0430\u043c-kissvk.com",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     3979166470
  ],
  [
     "13:43:14",
     "Goro-NoFly",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     2455695835
  ],
  [
     "13:45:37",
     "Goro-Road",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     3628123713
  ],
  [
     "13:47:53",
     "PAVELB4H-\u041c\u043d\u0435 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442 \u0431\u044b-kissvk.com",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     2278055077
  ],
  [
     "13:50:03",
     "BRANYA- MACAN-\u041f\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u0430\u043c-kissvk.com",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     3979166470
  ],
  [
     "13:52:25",
     "Goro-NoFly",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     2455695835
  ],
  [
     "13:55:02",
     "Goro-Road",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     3628123713
  ],
  [
     "13:57:02",
     "PAVELB4H-\u041c\u043d\u0435 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442 \u0431\u044b-kissvk.com",
     "img\/nocover.jpg",
     2278055077
  ]
]
```

Я использую библиотеку gson для того, чтобы брать этот JSON с URL следующим образом:

```java
url1 = new URL(sUrl);
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
request.connect();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 0):

В теории (не компилил, писал не в IDE) должно как-то так работать:

```
public class Data {
    public List<List<String>> songs;
}
```

---

```
String text = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Data data = new Gson().fromJson(text, Data.class);

List<String> songTitles = data.songDatas.stream().map { songData -> songData.get(1) }.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Самую последнюю и по всей видимости нужную для меня строку я и не понял: List<String> songTitles = data.songDatas.stream().map { songData -> songData.get(1) }.collect(Collectors.toList());
Как этим я раскрываю структуру Json ?

Comment: `final String songs = rootobj.getAsJsonObject("songs");` попробовал так, но это во-первых у меня не работает, а во-вторых мне еще надо как-то название песни вытянуть. Я вообще не имею понятия

Comment: `final String songs = rootobj.getAsJsonObject("songs");` - вот это не должно компилиться, т.к. вы не тот тип переменной указали. Да и смысла нет, если можно проще сделать. В моём коде примерно такое происходить должно: берётся ответ сервера, из него берётся массив массивов строк, преобразуется в поток и преобзазуется массив каждой песни в значение второго элемента этого массива, после чего собирается в список. Получается как раз список названий песен.

Comment: У меня map и get красным отмечаются без возможных решений в alt+enter (разве что rename references). А также ругается на .collect

Comment: Не обратил внимания на то, что у вас андроид. По идее, приведённый код будет для Java работать, если 8 версию java в build.gradle прописать и свежий плагин использовать: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support. Ну или перейти на котлин, и на нём тоже самое примерно написать.