# Как в java записать, прочитать, удалить и найти в json файле

Tags: java, json

И так, у меня есть код

```java
case "go":
    else if(args.length == 5){
        String nickname = p.getPlayer().getName();
        String name = args[1];
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
        System.out.println("Name - " + name + "; Nickname - " +nickname+"; XYZ = " + x + " " + y + " " + z);
    }
```

оно выводит `Name - home1; Nickname - ABOBA; XYZ = 3859 64 -5483`
но, как мне в json файл записать эти данные в таком формате

```json
    {
      "Homes": {
        "ABOBA": {
          "home1": {
            "X": "3859",
            "Y": "64",
            "Z": "-5483"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

но если данных много, то как их добавить ниже или в определённый участок, например у нас есть

```
Name - home1; Nickname - ABOBA; XYZ = 3859 64 -5483
Name - Dom; Nickname - leosens; XYZ = -3259 58 2483
Name - homes2; Nickname - ABOBA; XYZ = 359 -4 -239
Name - Shi; Nickname - Pol1sens; XYZ = 4958 32 2443
```

то нужно чтобы было так

```json
{
      "Homes": {
        "ABOBA": {
          "home1": {
            "X": "3859",
            "Y": "64",
            "Z": "-5483"
          },
          "homes2": {
            "X": "359",
            "Y": "-4",
            "Z": "-239"
          }
        },
        "leosens": {
          "Dom": {
            "X": "-3259",
            "Y": "58",
            "Z": "2483"
          }
        },
        "Pol1sens": {
          "Shi": {
            "X": "4958",
            "Y": "32",
            "Z": "2443"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

дальше, если эти данные записаны, то у меня есть ещё код

```java
case "go":
    if(args.length == 2) {
        String nickname = p.getPlayer().getName();
        String homename = args[1];
        System.out.println("Name - " + homename + "; Nickname - " + nickname);
    }
```

оно возвращает `Name - home1; Nickname - ABOBA`
так вот, как мне по `nickname` и `homename` в json файле найти по nickname и сравнить есть ли там homename, и если есть то достать из homename координаты и выполнить это

```java
// Location location = new Location("world", x, y, z);
// player.teleport(location);

Location location = new Location("world", /*тут x который в json файле*/,  /*тут y который в json файле*/,  /*тут z который в json файле*/);
p.teleport(location);
```

дальше, есть код который возвращает `Name - home1; Nickname - ABOBA`

```java
case "delete":
    if(args.length == 2) {
        String nickname = p.getPlayer().getName();
        String homename = args[1];
        System.out.println("Name - " + homename + "; Nickname - " + nickname);
    }
```

мне также по `nickname` нужно найти `homename` и если она есть то просто удалить её название с координатами

```java
case "list":
    if(args.length == 1) {
        String nickname = p.getPlayer().getName();
        System.out.println("Nickname - " + nickname);
    }
```

тут просто нужно по `nickname` найти все его homename's и вывести `System.out.println("Ваши дома - home1, homes2")`

Comment: блин ответа не будет скорее всего

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786175/4712268

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko я не понял(99

Comment: По ссылке указан код коорый поможет преобразовать любой объект в json. Фактически бросаешь в него некий объект с полями player, а оно вернет строку с каждым полем и его значением в json. не знаю что тут обхяснять. Правда, придется добавить библиотеку

Comment: Здесь представлен какой-то салат оливье из фрагментов кода и  разнообразных требований, разбейте ваши вопросы на несколько частей

Comment: Предполагаю, что вам нужно вот это, а вообще не понятно, что конкретно хотели бы
[Вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java)