# Ревью кода, сократить код

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Этот кусок кода выглядит страшно

```
let url = `${API_URL}api/tasks?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`
        
        if(!arrayIsEmpty(priorities)) {
            url = `${API_URL}api/tasks?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}&priorities=${JSON.stringify(priorities)}`
        }
        if(!arrayIsEmpty(statuses)) {
            url = `${API_URL}api/tasks?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}&statuses=${JSON.stringify(statuses)}`
        }
        if(!arrayIsEmpty(priorities) && !arrayIsEmpty(statuses)) {
            url = `${API_URL}api/tasks?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}&priorities=${JSON.stringify(priorities)}&statuses=${JSON.stringify(statuses)}`
        }
```

Можно ли как то сократить данный фрагмент?

Comment: да не оч..... начало положено в виде выделения общего url в переменную..... а дальше два if с конкатенацией.......... третий if  лишний

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не лишний, иначе он не сможет добавить сразу два параметра

Comment: @Grundy почему? если один параметр не пустой - добавляет его, если второй параметр не пустой - добавляет его.....два If'а вполне решают себе задачу. Т.к. URL общий и надо только лишь конкатенировать дополнительные данные, если нужно

Comment: @Grundy  обращу внимание на последний коммент вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1453395/191482 .... кстати он всё же минусанул ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745095/191482 ..... агрессивный какой-то.... в целом. надо беседы провести, как правильно вести сбея на ресурсе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, речь про конкретный код в вопросе. В нем третий if не лишний.

Comment: @Grundy лишний!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если его убрать, то при текущем коде добавится только один параметр.

Comment: @Grundy так смысл в том, чтобы работать с общим url и конкатенировать, а не перезаписывать url каждый раз. Об этом я написал в самом первом же комментарии

Answer (score 1):

Думаю плодить по одному `if`у каждый раз когда добавляется новый `GET` параметр, - плохая идея. Есть смысл собрать их в один объект

```
const searchParameters = {
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    priorities: priorities,
    statuses: statuses
}
```

Чтобы вручную не билдить url можно использовать стандартный класс `URL`, далее циклом проходимся по всем свойствам объекта `searchParameters`, делаем необходимые проверки на пустоту на тип итд и добавляем их в параметры объекта `URL`

```
url = new URL(`${API_URL}api/tasks`);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(searchParameters)) {
    if(Array.isArray(value) || Object.is(value)) {
        if(! arrayIsEmpty(value)) {
            url.searchParams.append(key, JSON.stringify(value))
        }
    } else if(value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        url.searchParams.append(key, value)
    }

}
```

таким образом при добавлении еще одного параметра поиска не нужно менять логику билда, достаточно добавить еще одно свойство в `searchParameters`

Вот собственно весь код (Написан чисто для наглядности алгоритма, прошу жеесников не бить :D)

```
const searchParameters = {
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    priorities: priorities,
    statuses: statuses
},
    url = new URL(`${API_URL}api/tasks`);


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(searchParameters)) {
    if(Array.isArray(value) || Object.is(value)) {
        if(! arrayIsEmpty(value)) {
            url.searchParams.append(key, JSON.stringify(value))
        }
    } else if(value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        url.searchParams.append(key, value)
    }

}

console.log(url.href)
```