# Что такое json объект?

Tags: java, json

Читаю сейчас гайды по вебсокетам с spring. И во всех пишут про json-объект. Вписывают

```
{
"from": "John",
"text": "Hello!"
```

Куда они это пишут и куда сохраняют?

Comment: С точки зрения json, объект - это то что в фигурных скобках. Это просто текст.

Comment: Хорошо, это ясно. Куда это пишут, куда сохраняют, как код должен понять что это json ?

Comment: Просто в String запишите, и будет вам json объект. Код никак сам не понимает, что это json. json - это "внешнее" представление (например, java объектов), которое можно например записать в файл или отправить http запросом на сервер.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и чем парсить Json на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Comment: JSON это просто строка определённого вида. Так что JSON-объект это какое-то безграмотное определение. 
В контексте веб-сокетов вам видимо нужно просто уметь формировать, отправлять и получать такие строки и уметь доставать из них данные.

Comment: То есть, то что в фигурных скобках я показал, это просто в гайдах пишут для наглядности ?

Comment: @Artemiy не знаю, что вы имеете в виду под наглядностью. То что в фигурных скобках пишут (вместе с фигурными скобками) - это и есть JSON. Буквально, этот текст - это и есть JSON.

Comment: Хорошо, это JSON. Этот текст, нужно сохранять в отдельном файле с форматом .json?

Comment: Это просто текст, его можно хранить как вам нужно. В программе это может быть переменная типа String, или это может быть текстовый файл. Вы же не спрашиваете нужно ли текст "Hello, World" сохранять в файл с расширением txt?

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо, теперь все стало предельно ясно.

Answer (score -1):

Вот смотрите, допустим у меня есть какой-то класс DTO, объекты которого я использую ==>
[image: класс DTO в котором есть конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры + ...]

У меня есть POST-контроллер, который принимает на вход объект этого класса
[image: POST - контроллер]

Одна из замечательных способностей Spring в том, что он берет на себя маршаллинг/демаршаллинг - преобразование из объекта в JSON/из JSON в объект.

Т.е. если я направлю в контроллер вот такой POST запрос ==> [image: POST запрос]
на входе Spring преобразует этот JSON (объект) в объект соответствующего класса DTO и POST контроллер сможет его обработать

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)